# how to iterate over object and replace {keys} inside a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have string mentioned below. i want to replace {keys} with object value whose key name match inside string.

`Dear {user}, Your account for Portal has been created against this Email Address {email}.`

and JSON like this.

```
{
   "user": "John Wick",
   "email": "some@email.com"
}
```

I want to iterate over each key inside object and check if that key exists in string replace key with object key value.

Expected result
`Dear John Wick, Your account for Portal has been created against this Email Address some@email.com.`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this example would walk over the keys of the JSON and replace any occurrence that is wrapped in curly braces.

```js
const userDetails = {
   "user": "John Wick",
   "email": "some@email.com"
};

const result = Object.keys(userDetails).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc.replace(`{${curr}}`, userDetails[curr])
}, `Dear {user}, Your account for Portal has been created against this Email Address {email}.`)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i am looking for a dynamic way not like this. i have different templates with different json key values.

Comment: @MuhammadFazeel that is not what you asked. Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: just updated the code @MuhammadFazeel

Comment: @MuhammadFazeel no need to apologize, I'm glad you could solve your issue.